# How to make cell of gridview scratchable

Tags: java, android, gridview

I am working on a app where i need to build 3*3 scratch card..i am using 3*3 grid view and populating it with a adapter, now i don't have any idea how to animate each cell to show some scratch effects. following is my adapter getview code  :

`

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageview =  new ImageView(mycontext);
    imageview.setImageResource(picids[position]);
    imageview.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    imageview.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(90,90));        
    return imageview  ;
}
```

`

Comment: so do you want to provide scratch view over the image? so that user can scratch particular card, right?

Comment: I feel you need a canvas also for this. where a layer( kind of foil) will be laid over the gridview. This foil will have some color(say silver). Now when user touch the screen, you need to make the touch points of transparent color. That can give you illusion of scratch

Comment: right @PareshMayani ..i need to pprovide scratch view over the image, so that user can scratch particular card.